# plotting a matlab function over different values

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 3 functions in Matlab:

```
function [turbine] = turbem(a,t)

turbine=zeros(size(a));
c1=a<90;
c2=a>90 & a<270;
c3=a>270;

turbine(c1)=0;
turbine(c2)=t*0.5*(1+cos((a*pi)/90));
turbine(c3)=0;

end
```

```
function [compressor]=compem(a,c)

compressor=zeros(size(a));
c1=a<=90;
c2=a>90 & a<270;
c3=a>=270;

compressor(c1)=abs(cos((a*pi/180)))*c;
compressor(c2)=0;
compressor(c3)=abs(cos((a*pi/180)))*c;

end
```

```
function [plume]=plumem(a,p)

plume=zeros(size(a));
c1=a<90;
c2=a>=90 & a<=270;
c3=a>270;

plume(c1)=(a/90)*p;
plume(c2)=1*p;
plume(c3)=((360-a)/90)*p;

end
```

All functions work out a value for emission of heat from different parts of engines on an aeroplane, dependant on the angle that it's viewed at as from some angles you will not see certain parts of the engine.

This next part allows me to input values, and get the desired endpoint which is the total emission dependant on how many engines can be seen.

```
a=input('Enter Azimuth Angle');
t=input('Enter Turbine Emission Component');
c=input('Enter Compressor Emission Component');
p=input('Enter Plume Emission Component');
b=input('Enter Body Emission Component');

engemission=(turbem(a,t)+compem(a,c)+plumem(a,p)+b)
totalengines=(e1(a)+e2(a)+e3(a)+e4(a))
totalemission=totalengines*engemission
```

the e1(a),e2(a) etc look like this:
    function engine1=e1(a)

```
engine1=zeros(size(a));
c1=a<=45;
c2=a>45 & a<155;
c3=a>=155;

engine1(c1)=1;
engine1(c2)=0;
engine1(c3)=1;

end
```

Basically, I want to be able to plot various aspects of this over all angles `0:5:360`. I would like to see a graph of `turbem`, `compem`, `plumem` and then finally `totalemission` for all values from 0 to 360 in increments of 5.

Is this possible? And how?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than receiving an input for a you'll define a to be 0->360 degrees in steps of 5, then convert to radians.

```
a=pi*(0:5:360)/180;
```

Then calculate your emission components for these angles exactly as you're doing, then use a polar plot to present them

```
polar(a,totalemission);
```

for the terms you're not explicitly saving like `turbem(a,t)` you should store them in a new variable such as `turbineEmission` so that you can plot them without recalculating.

I haven't checked your implementation in detail, but it seems to be sufficiently vectorized for this approach to work fine.  One thing to note is that you are better off not storing your logical arrays into the c1,c2 and c3 variables.  So for example in e1 you'd use

```
engine1(a<=45)=1;
engine1(a>45 & a<155)=0;
engine1(a>=155)=1;
```

Update: well, ignore that last part.  Looks like there is negligible speed difference between the two implementations on 2011b (Thanks Matlab!)